# loop updates table but also gets system exceeds resources error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am running the loop below in a macro. It finishes updating the table but I always get a "system resources exceed"... I was wondering what could be wrong...

Or a better way of doing it...

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("temp_group")

rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
  If IsNull(rst!AvgOfT1_discount) Then
     rst.Edit
     rst!AvgOfT1_discount = 0
     rst.Update
  End If

  If IsNull(rst!AvgOfT2_discount) Then
     rst.Edit
     rst!AvgOfT2_discount = 0
     rst.Update
  End If

  If IsNull(rst!AvgOfT3_discount) Then
     rst.Edit
     rst!AvgOfT3_discount = 0
     rst.Update
  End If

  If IsNull(rst!AvgOfT4_discount) Then
     rst.Edit
     rst!AvgOfT4_discount = 0
     rst.Update
  End If

  rst.MoveNext
Loop

Set rst = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with no errors, though could be simplified like this to only edit once per record:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("temp_group")

rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
  If IsNull(rst!AvgOfT1_discount.Value + rst!AvgOfT2_discount.Value + rst!AvgOfT3_discount.Value + rst!AvgOfT4_discount.Value) Then
     rst.Edit
     If IsNull(rst!AvgOfT1_discount.Value) Then
         rst!AvgOfT1_discount.Value = 0
     End If
     If IsNull(rst!AvgOfT2_discount.Value) Then
         rst!AvgOfT2_discount.Value = 0
     End If
     If IsNull(rst!AvgOfT3_discount.Value) Then
         rst!AvgOfT3_discount.Value = 0
     End If
     If IsNull(rst!AvgOfT4_discount.Value) Then
         rst!AvgOfT4_discount.Value = 0
     End If
     rst.Update
  End If
  rst.MoveNext
Loop

Set rst = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

For this it looks like an update query might work better - or four update queries in this case. You could make the code something like this:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE [temp_group] SET [temp_group].[AvgOfT1_discount] = 0 WHERE ((([temp_group].[AvgOfT1_discount])=Null))"
CurrentDb.Execute (strSQL)
```

etc.

That would convert the Null entries to 0. or you could save the update queries and call them with VBA

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I do not know why, but on the queries access did not consider the field as null... the above query do not update the empty fields..